# Diferença entre duas datas em PHP em meses de 31, 28 e 29 dias

Tags: php, data, time

Eu tenho um sistema de bônus que apenas libera o bônus após 30 dias exatos do cadastro do usuário. Para comparar a data atual com a data do cadastro do usuário de forma que eu obtenha quantos dias faltam para completar 30 dias exatos, utilizo o seguinte código `PHP`:

```
$time1 = new DateTime($user->date); //data do cadastro do usuário (MySQL timestamp)
$time2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")); //data atual
$interval =  $time2->diff($time1);
$faltam_dias = 30 - $interval->d;
```

**Dúvida:**

Fiz esse teste no mês atual (junho) que contém exatos 30 dias. Caso o mês atual tenha 31 ou 28/29(fevereiro) dias, como faria para obter de forma correta quantos dias faltariam para completar os 30 dias do bônus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a propriedade [`days`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days) em vez de `d`:

```
$time1 = new DateTime('20150501'); 
$time2 = new DateTime(); //data atual
$interval =  $time2->diff($time1);
echo $interval->days;
```

http://ideone.com/zK0P2E

Answer (score -2):

Utilize +1 Mês... ao invés de 30 dias, talvez facilitaria muito a utilização do seu código....

```
$data_inicial = 2017-07-01;
$data_final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1 Month', $data_inicial));
echo $data_final;
```

Creio que será impresso:

> 2017-08-01

e creio também que será possível entregar 12 bônus exatamente por ano

:)